# Why wrapping my JS SignalR callback my $(function() makes it not triggered?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

Why wrapping my SignalR callback (from .NET C# server-side hub to JavaScript client-side) in a `$(document).ready` handler or via its shorthand `$(function()` makes this particular callback not triggered (the handling of `start` `done` and disconnected work regardless of them being wrapped or not...):

Server-side - C# Hub:

```
public class AppointmentHub : Hub
{
    public void RefreshSchedulers(string ownerConnectionId, string userId)
    {
        Clients.User(userId).refreshScheduler(ownerConnectionId);
    }
}
```

Client-Side - JavaScript hub proxy + callback:

```
[...]

function getSchedulerInstance() {
    return $('#scheduler').scheduler('instance');
}

$(function () {

        // If I move this handler below out of the jQuery document ready ( $(function ()) ... it works... why?
        $.connection.appointmentHub.client.refreshScheduler = function(ownerConnectionId) {
            if (getAppointmentHubConnectionId() !== ownerConnectionId) {
                getSchedulerInstance().repaint();
            }
        };

        $.connection.appointmentHub.connection.disconnected(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.connection.appointmentHub.connection.start();
                },
                500);
        });

        $.connection.appointmentHub.connection.logging = true;

        $.connection.appointmentHub.connection.start().done(function() {
        });

});

function getAppointmentHubConnectionId() {
    return $.connection.appointmentHub.connection.id;
}

function refreshScheduler() {
    $.connection.appointmentHub.server.refreshSchedulers(getAppointmentHubConnectionId(), '@User.Identity.GetUserId()');
}

[...]

// Stuff below works
function onAppointmentDeleted(e) {
    ui.notify("Appointment deleted.", "success", 600);
    refreshScheduler();
}

function onAppointmentUpdated(e) {
    refreshScheduler();
}

function onAppointmentAdded(e) {
    refreshScheduler();
}
```

Can't really figure out, I checked in debug mode the hub is calling the `refreshScheduler` so everything should be okay.

[EDIT]
Added some logs: `$.connection.appointmentHub.connection.logging = true;`

Client 1 (Google Chrome)

```
[18:55:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:55:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:52539/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=83lZVSflIHfvK0aJmXokuuQ9lC5%2F4WV6wtzkGcWKXBLrVPhQWC41mduPmu%2FMs3XM%2BezlduQ%2FKoSodH9HouPXECFS69bvKe770QV8iJbFusZPIgxLbFsLNOT8cWDsuV30hUE5QoFhjqBWto7%2BUAYnww%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22userhub%22%7D%5D&tid=7'.
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:55:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:55:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:55:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:55:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:55:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:55:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoked appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:56:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js:9 [18:56:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoked appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
```

Client 2 (Internet Explorer 11)

```
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'appointmenthub'.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'userhub'.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22appointmenthub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22userhub%22%7D%5D'.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:52539/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=rWeJC23FIMc%2FXJcoF4kw3DNAJIDLk6tZXgKAMe2qWo6jq3TWwwDm0FqgWq%2F7CE3VGer%2FPVKi7hYOqryGcMVvTE1%2BGuBdNhYn76X1u1rw5p3AHuFOn%2BxPFPca0%2FDnYIcV3P5bxQUDZG1IqZL6MGw12w%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22appointmenthub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22userhub%22%7D%5D&tid=4'.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[18:55:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
[18:55:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'refreshScheduler' on hub 'AppointmentHub'.
[18:55:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
[18:55:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'refreshScheduler' on hub 'AppointmentHub'.
[18:55:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoked appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
[18:55:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
[18:55:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'refreshScheduler' on hub 'AppointmentHub'.
[18:55:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoked appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
[18:56:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
[18:56:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'refreshScheduler' on hub 'AppointmentHub'.
[18:56:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoked appointmenthub.RefreshSchedulers
[18:56:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'refreshScheduler' on hub 'AppointmentHub'.
```

For some reasons it works from Chrome to IE11 but not the other way around...
I don't think it's related to the browser cause I tried to open another tab in IE and also connect with Opera but it's still the first instance from Chrome to the first instance IE11 that is working... getting the handler out of the ready fix that behaviour... still don't really get what's going on.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke the refreshScheduler before the page has been fully parsed into the DOM?  Since the definition of the refreshScheduler is being created in the document ready, it will not exist until after that point and that logic runs.  Or are you saying that it executes properly this way, but something inside it errors?

Comment: @Taplar The invocation is only performed after the page has been fully loaded.

Comment: So what exactly is the error you are seeing in your console?

Comment: @Taplar No error actually... I am going to copy paste some logs

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the handler before you start the connection. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callclient) contains more details.

Comment: I know that was the case in my code, going to update my initial post. Still didnt work except from one particular browser to another one